# Vectorize cosine similarity in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 1000x1000x3 3d matrix. I want to calculate the cosine of the angle between each 3d vector of a certain set and each 3d vector I can vertically extract from the 3d matrix. Then I should be able to create a 1000x1000 matrix with the index of the vector that has the maximum cosine similarity (i.e. minimum angle) with the original data.

How can I vectorize this calculation or at least some parts of it? Currently I do it with nested for loops (huge amount of time and overhead).

Comment: yes you can. did you try it? if so where are you stuck? if your code is running consider asking on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for improvements.

Comment: Check [`pdist2`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) (Statistics Toolbox) with the the `'cosine'` option

Comment: @BeyelerStudios can't manage to understand how this kind of vectorization could be done. I'm not a matlab expert!

Comment: Could you include those nested loops?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate cosine similarity between two frequency vectors in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187941/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-between-two-frequency-vectors-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a function that takes the norm over the third dimension, but this works as well I think.

```
a = rand(1000,1000,3)-.5; %dataset
na = sqrt(a(:,:,1).^2+a(:,:,2).^2+a(:,:,3).^2); %the norm of each vector
b = [1.2,1,3]; %vector to compare angle against
nb = norm(b); %the norm of the compare vector
b = repmat(b,[1000,1000]);
b = reshape(b,[1000,1000,3]); %1000x1000 copies of b
pl = a.*nb + na.*b; 
mn = a.*nb - na.*b;
npl = sqrt(pl(:,:,1).^2+pl(:,:,2).^2+pl(:,:,3).^2);  
nmn = sqrt(mn(:,:,1).^2+mn(:,:,2).^2+mn(:,:,3).^2);  
theta = 2 * atan(nmn./npl); %angle between [0 and pi] as expected
```

The math is an adaptation of this formula:

```
theta = 2 * atan(norm(x*norm(y) - norm(x)*y) / norm(x * norm(y) + norm(x) * y))
```